# How to set cookie secure flag using javascript

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, get

I have tried to set a cookie using `document.cookie = "tagname = test; secure"` but this does not set the secure flag. Am I setting it wrong? Can you only set it from a server response? I am also wondering that, because I have had a difficult time finding an example of its use, that it probably is not commonly used?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**TL:DR**

```
document.cookie = "tagname = test;secure";
```

**You have to use HTTPS to set a secure attribute**

The normal (or formal, maybe) name is attribute. Since the flag refers to other things.

**More Info**

### Cookie attributes:

> Secure - Cookie will be sent in HTTPS transmission only.
>
> HttpOnly- Don't allow scripts to access cookie. You can set both of the Secure and HttpOnly.
>
> Domain- specify the hosts to which the cookie will be sent.
>
> Path - create scopes, cookie will be sent only if the path matches.
>
> Expires - indicates the maximum lifetime of the cookie.

More details and practical usages. Check [Testing_for_cookies_attributes_(OTG-SESS-002)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_cookies_attributes_(OTG-SESS-002))

**UPDATES**
**The following contents expire in June 2, 2016.**

### <del>Cookie Flags</del>

Cookie flags are prefixes. At the moment, they are described in the [RFC draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-cookie-prefixes-05) as a update to the [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

**These flags are used with the 'secure' attribute.**

```
__Secure-
```

> The dash is a part of the prefix. This flag tells the browser, the cookie should only be included in 'https'.

```
__Host-
```

**A cookie with this flag**

> 1. must not have 'domain' attribute, it will be only sent to the host which set it.
> 2. Must have a 'path' attribute, that is set to '/', because it will be sent to the host in every request from the host.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I was trying to set the secure attribute without being in HTTPS.

Comment: I tried your `document.cookie = "tagname = test;secure";` but `document.cookie` return `tagname=test`, https, tested in current versions of Chromium and Firefox. UPD, oh, I found `secure` flag in cookie viewer inside Devtools.

Comment: MDN specifically mentions it's forbidden. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#JavaScript_access_using_Document.cookie

Comment: @sfy I have to set secure true so what change required this is my js code ->     document.cookie = `cookie_consent=${value}; expires=${expireDate} Secure; path=/`;
??

Comment: @PriyenMehta You need to check if you are contacting your server with HTTPS, and your server does support HTTPS.

Answer (score 5):

This cookie package is easy to use @ https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie

```
 //to set cookie use
 Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '' });

 //to read the cookie, use
 Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'

 //to delete cookie this
 Cookies.remove('name')

  //to set secure cookie this
 Cookies.set('name', 'value', { secure: true });
```

Comment: the 7 in the expires means 7 days

Answer (score 4):

because the flag is called [`secure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), not *security*:

```
document.cookie = "tagname = test;secure";
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my original post. I have since corrected it. When using Chrome console, when I type: `document.cookie = "tagname = test;secure";` no cookies get added, but when I type  `document.cookie = "tagname = test";` it does get added. Is this a limitation of entering things into the Chrome console? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose Are you trying this on a HTTPS website? It works for me just fine, but you have to do it on a HTTPS website.

Answer (score 1):

Although the server responded with Upper case, and separate with space:

```
set-cookie: x = y; Secure
```

The client javascript needs to lowercase the `secure` and delete the whitespace after `;`, like so:

```
document.cookie = `x=y;secure`;
```

Otherwise, it will be no effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for ExpressJs users:

> Set secure cookie

```
res.cookie("name", "value", { secure: true });
```

> Read this cookie

```
req.cookies["name"];
```

> When the `Secure` attribute is set on a cookie, the browser will include it in
> the request only when the request is made through [`HTTPS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and not through
> [`HTTP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) .
>
> It's a best practice to use this attribute for sensitive cookies as it will
> protect them from being sent over insecure connection.