# Cookie secure flag using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I want inform about how to set cookie secure flag and http flag using javascript. When I open in chrome developer tools with F12 and click "Application->cookies" I see no flag here (in secure and http column), this is my code to set cookie:

```
document.cookie = name+'='+value+'; expires='+expires+'; path=/;';
```

I also find this topic, but this not help me: [How to set cookie secure flag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234687/how-to-set-cookie-secure-flag-using-javascript/37235621)

Comment: Add `secure` to the end of your string. Done?

Comment: secure at end of my string is not my solution (not work well), because the whole cookie then disappears, do not load

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Because you need that for `secure`.

Comment: No, I am using http

Comment: Then you're not in a secure setup, thus `secure` will (correctly) not make the cookie appear for you.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try https.

Comment: I try it and in https secure flag works, but what about HTTP flag?

Comment: If you set the httpOnly flag correctly, it won't appear in your JavaScript anyway... What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve that flag, because I got from Horus test that this two thing i have wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to create `HttpOnly` cookie with JavaScript. `**HttpOnly**` Cookie means it is not accessible by scripting languages. And therefore it cannot be created by Javascript.

> To prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, **HttpOnly** cookies are inaccessible to JavaScript's Document.cookie API; they are only sent to the server. For example, cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript, and the HttpOnly flag should be set.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies