# setting up the cookies both secure and httponly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up cookies using JavaScript code for both the secure and HttpOnly but the Secure and httpOnly is always false, how can I make both true?

Here is my code

```
document.getElementById("acceptButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var now = new Date();
        now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 3); 
        var ID = document.getElementById("acceptButton").getAttribute("data-ID");
    
    document.cookie = "cookie_" + ID + "=true; path=/";
    document.cookie = "cookie_" + ID + "=true; path=/; secure"; 
    document.cookie = "cookie_" + ID + "=true; path=/; HttpOnly";  // this section is not setting it for true  
    document.getElementById("cookieAlert").style.display = "none";
    });
```

I am not sure at this point what is wrong with this code but it should be setting up both to true

I have already tried the above solution

Comment: The whole point of having `httpOnly` cookies is to don't make them accessible by JavaScript, thus there's no way to create them from JavaScript either. Your server should set it, this is what `httpOnly` means

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set cookie secure flag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234687/how-to-set-cookie-secure-flag-using-javascript)